# How to Share Methods Between Classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I want to set the text of a label to the text of a cell from a different class.

In my MasterViewController I have:

```
// SAVE TEXT OF SELECTED CELL

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cellString = cell.textLabel.text;
}

//SHARES VARIABLES BETWEEN CLASSES

- (ChemProjectMasterViewController*) sharedVariable
{
    static ChemProjectMasterViewController *myVariable = nil;

    if (myVariable == nil)
    {
        myVariable = [[[self class] alloc] init];
        myVariable.sharedCellString = cellString;
    }

    return myVariable;
}
```

I also have this in the .h

```
@interface ChemProjectMasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic)NSString *cellString;
@property (nonatomic)NSString *sharedCellString;
+(ChemProjectMasterViewController*) sharedVariable;

@end
```

Now the class I want to access this method from is DetailViewController. In that I have:

```
detailDescriptionLabel.text = [ChemProjectMasterViewController sharedVariable].sharedCellString;
```

Where the detailDescriptionLabel is just a text label.

**
The program compiles fine but I have the label text set to change when I click a button. The app runs smooth until I hit the button which causes it to crash. The main goal is to set the label text in DetailViewController to the text of a cell from MasterViewController. Thank you for any help!

Comment: At the risk of being too obvious, `detailDescriptionLabel.text` is expecting a string. You're passing in a view controller. Why?

Comment: @StevenFisher - He's actually passing in a string. He access a property called `sharedCellString` of a variable called `sharedVariable` from the class `ChemProjectMasterViewController`.

Comment: @jtetreault13 You Declare in its header as `+(ChemProjectMasterViewController*) sharedVariable;` and in .m File you are defining it as `-(ChemProjectMasterViewController*) sharedVariable`, I am not sure but this can create a problem.

Comment: Oh, you're right. The extra spaces (since removed) on the `[ChemProjectMasterViewController sharedVariable]` pushed the property off to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing few things.

First one, in .h you have declared as class method (+), while in .m it is instance (-).

Second one is `@property (nonatomic)NSString *sharedCellString;` which is unsafe unretained, make it strong.

And kindly let me know, if it works ?

Comment: well I made the sharedCellString strong and it did not seem to do anything, still got the same SIGABRT. Now when I went into the .h and changed it from a class method (+) to an instance (-) and it throws an error saying "Property 'sharedCellString' not found on object of type 'id'"